# Problema Año Datapicker JS

Tags: javascript, datepicker, jquery-datepicker

Estoy generando un datepicker (el cual ya funciona) pero no me carga los años anteriores (es un calendario de fecha de nacimiento) SOlo me figura el año actual

```
function cargarNacimiento(){
    var date    = new Date();

    $('#fechaNacimientoPersona').daterangepicker({ 
        format              :   'DD/MM/YYYY',
        startDate           :   '01/01/',
        endDate             :   '31/01/',
        minDate             :   '01/01/',
        maxDate             :   '31/12/',
        singleDatePicker    :   true,
        showDropdowns       :   true,
        showWeekNumbers     :   false,
        opens   :'center',
        "locale": {
            "separator": " - ",
            "applyLabel": "Aplicar",
            "cancelLabel": "Cancelar",
            "fromLabel": "DE",
            "toLabel": "HASTA",
            "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
            "daysOfWeek": [
                "Dom",
                "Lun",
                "Mar",
                "Mie",
                "Jue",
                "Vie",
                "S&aacute;b"
            ],
            "monthNames": [
                "Enero",
                "Febrero",
                "Marzo",
                "Abril",
                "Mayo",
                "Junio",
                "Julio",
                "Agosto",
                "Septiembre",
                "Octubre",
                "Noviembre",
                "Diciembre"
            ],
            "firstDay": 1
      }});

    $('#fechaNacimientoPersona').val('');

}
```

Comment: Has probado a rellenar el año en `startDate           :   '01/01/',
        endDate             :   '31/01/',
        minDate             :   '01/01/',
        maxDate             :   '31/12/',`?

Comment: intenta cambiar los valores de startdate, enddate, mindate y maxdate con fechas poniendole los años, los 2 primeros puede ser el rando que quieres inicialmente, el ultimo puedes no ponerlo, y el tercero debe ser la fecha minima hasta donde kieres ke se pueda elegir si 3 años, o 2 o solo 1, solo tienes ke calcular y ponerle ese valor

Answer (score 1):

Las opciones `minDate` y `maxDate` definen los valores mínimos y máximos aceptados por ese *datepicker*, deberías cambiar los límites a algo como *"desde hace 120 años hasta hoy*". Puesto que [también acepta números (número de días hacia atrás)](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate), podrías poner algo como

```
...
minDate: 120 *365, //120 años, en días,
maxDate: 0, //hoy
...
```